# Trim the values in td tag such that fractional part can be of two digits in a jsp

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, trim

I have to trim values in td column and then set the background such that if integer_part.## is zero then lime colur should be dispalyed otherwise pink.

**`Values are trimmed in Integer_part.## format.`**

I tried with following code-

```
<td style="${r.p99_dacbyadc-row.p99_dacbyadc <=00.00 || r.p99_dacbyadc-row.p99_dacbyadc <=0.00 || r.p99_dacbyadc-row.p99_dacbyadc <=000.00? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p99_dacbyadc-row.p99_dacbyadc)}" maxFractionDigits="2" var="mm" ></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${mm}" ></c:out></td>
```

But its not correct as pink color comes when value is zero.

I also tried this code-

```
<td style="${r.p66_setvalue-row.p66_setvalue eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p66_setvalue-row.p66_setvalue)}" maxFractionDigits="2"   var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
 <c:out value="${mm}" ></c:out></td>
```

But same issues this also shows.

whats wrong with the code??

Answer (score 0):

The second one is way more readable/maintainable, so lets use it.

You are only trimming what you are displaying, not what you are testing against.  The untrimmed version probably is not equal to zero.  So ... trim it first, then use the trimmed value for the display test:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${r.p66_setvalue - row.p66_setvalue}" maxFractionDigits="2" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<td style="${mm eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}">
<c:out value="${mm}" ></c:out></td>
```

Comment: @aifreema,i did this also,but then also it was showing pink color if the truncated value is 00.00

Comment: Then your requirement isn't clear to me.   Please update your question with some actual example numbers when it should be pink and when it should be green.

Comment: I do not want the - sign in front of the difference calculated ,I just want the magnitude of difference .For example I want to see the magnitude of **r.p99_dacbyadc-row.p99_dacbyadc**,What to use in expression langugae??

Comment: Then change this ${mm} to ${mm < 0 ? mm * -1 : mm}